# Socket io connection from one page in Yii2

Tags: socket.io, namespaces, yii2

I am using Yii advanced project with socket io and nodejs. 
My server.js is located in yii2advanced/nodejs.

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');
var connectedUsers = {};

server.listen(8890);

io.of('frontend/views/project/index').on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('usersocket', function(data) {
        connectedUsers[data] = socket;
        console.log("new client with Id: " + data + " added to CLIENTS list");
    });
});
```

My client.js is located in yii2advanced/frontend/web/js.

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8890/frontend/views/project/index');

    socket.on('connect', function () {
        socket.emit('usersocket', user_id);
});
```

I need to allow socket to connect only from frontend/views/project/index.php page.
Now socket connects even from frontend/web/index.php
I followed an example from socket docs ('Restricting yourself to a namespace') but I am not sure if I specify the namespaces correctly.

Comment: :: did you get any answer !

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue as following.

I created new layout `project_layout` for my `project/index action` (before all code in this `action` I wrote `$this->layout = 'project_layout';`). 
I created new `AssetBundle` (ProjectAsset). Inside this `Asset` I wrote:

```
public $js = ['js/client.js'];
```

Inside new `layout` I registered new `ProjectAsset`:

```
use frontend\assets\ProjectAsset;
ProjectAsset::register($this);
```

So an idea is to use client.js only on page you need. Before this changes I had only one `main layout` for all `actions`. Thus on each page I had an `AppAsset` with `client.js` attached. Now it is attached only on `project/index` page.

Comment: Exactly what I needed and it worked exactly like you said. Thanks for sharing!